# AngularJS separate login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, external

I use AngularJS and i need my login html and javascript files load first, and when user is logged load the rest of javascript files. I use Grunt Bower and Yo to create the application, when build my application all javascript file unifi and minify in one only file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting js into angular application is hard and hacky once it is initialized. I recommend you to split them into two applications with server supported redirect, if you need that kind of stuff.

Comment: you are right, i separately, now i have two apps. Thank you.